# Using two textbox to search certain date

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

Can't filter out the date in the grid view. I'm using 2 textboxes to search between a certain date, but the `GridView` did not change.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="searchdate1" type="date" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="searchdate2" type="date" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>

try
{
    using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString2"].ConnectionString))
    {
        con.Open();
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM TBLPINOY WHERE BIRTHDAY BETWEEN '"+searchdate1.Text+"'and'"+searchdate2.Text+"'";
        using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            OracleDataReader odr;
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            odr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            gv.DataSource = odr;
            gv.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

Comment: So what's the problem? What errors do you get, or what did you expect to happen that didn't happen? Code without an explanation probably isn't going to get much attention - please edit your question and tell us what's going on. Thanks.

Comment: It does not have an error. But the date in the textbox can't find the data in the gridview @BobJarvis

Comment: What valued do you enter in the textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `TO_Date()` to your query.

```
using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString2"].ConnectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM TBLPINOY WHERE BIRTHDAY BETWEEN TO_DATE('"+searchdate1.Text+"', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('"+searchdate2.Text+"', 'DD/MM/YYYY')";

    using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        OracleDataReader odr;
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        odr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        gv.DataSource = odr;
        gv.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use parametrized query with bind variables. Otherwise you open the door for SQL-Injection.

Comment: Top was sample to query between date only. It was good to apply parameters to prevent from sql injections.